# Non-Linear Differential: Population model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the ODE:

$$u'(t) = c_1\,u(t) -c_2\,u(t)^2 \quad \text{with starting condition $u(0) = u_0 <\dfrac{c_1}{c_2}$}$$

Substitution $u = \dfrac{1}{w} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad u' = -w'\,\dfrac{1}{w^2}$

As to linearize the ODE:

$$-w' = c_1\,w-c_2  \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad w' = -c_1\,w+c_2$$

Now, solving that apparently easy ODE I get:

$$\frac{c_2}{c_1}\left(1-e^{-c_1\,t}\right)+w_0\,e^{-c_1\,t}$$

And finally substitution back: $w = \dfrac{1}{u}, \quad w_0 = \dfrac{1}{u_0}$:

$$\dfrac{1}{u} = \frac{c_2}{c_1}\left(1-e^{-c_1\,t}\right)+\dfrac{1}{u_0}\,e^{-c_1\,t} \\[24pt]
u = \dfrac{c_1}{c_2\,\left(1-e^{-c_1\,t}\right)+\dfrac{c_1}{u_0}\,e^{-c_1\,t}}$$

As comparison I was solving the same ODE (hoping it was the same one) with MATLAB receiving:

$$-\frac{c_{1}\,\left(\mathrm{tanh}\left(\mathrm{atanh}\left(\frac{c_{1}-2\,c_{2}\,w_{0}}{c_{1}}\right)-\frac{c_{1}\,t}{2}\right)-1\right)}{2\,c_{2}}$$

Even tho the solutions look terrifyingly different, there plots are quite similar. However, it seems like I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compare with
$$
\tanh(a-s/2)-1=\frac{e^{2a-s}-1}{e^{2a-s}+1}-1=-\frac{2}{e^{2a}e^{-s}+1}
$$
to see that both expressions are indeed compatible, and after carefully comparing constants, also equivalent.
\begin{align}
s&=c_1t\\
e^{2a}&=\frac{c_1}{c_2u_0}-1\\
\tanh(a)&=\frac{e^{2a}-1}{e^{2a}+1}=\frac{c_1-2c_2u_0}{c_1}
\end{align}

---

To get directly to the matlab form, make a constant shift in $u$ so that the linear term on the right side vanishes,
$$
4c_2u'(t)=2·c_1·(2c_2u(t))-(2c_2u(t))^2=c_1^2-(2c_2u(t)-c_1)^2
$$
and then apply the substitution $2c_2u(t)-c_1=c_1\tanh(v(t))$, $v(0)={\rm atanh}(2\frac{c_2}{c_1}u(0)-1)$, which is valid due to the range restriction of the initial value that translates into a range restriction for the solution. Then
$$
c_1(1-\tanh^2(v(t)))\,v'(t)=2c_2u'=\frac{c_1^2}{2}(1-\tanh^2(v(t)))\\~\\
\implies v'(t)=\frac{c_1}2\\~\\
v(t)=v(0)+\frac{c_1}2t
\\~\\
u(t)=\frac{c_1}{2c_2}\left(\tanh\left({\rm atanh}\left(2\frac{c_2}{c_1}u(0)-1\right)+\frac{c_1}2t\right)+1\right)
$$

Comment: Oh, you have said equivalent. I've skipped that while reading your comment. Now I just need to figure out why plots are not similar. If the MATLAB community will get it right u'll get the tick, since I'm not that well versed in seeing the equivalence through the addition theorems.

Comment: You have in the question, the back substitution, and apparently also in the matlab code written $w_0$ where you mean $u_0$.

Comment: Indeed I made a really stupid mistake while typing the formula causing me a lot of time asking all of that. But therefore I've got a really beautiful equality and variable shifting from you! Really incredible how you did spot it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

The ODE $u'(t) = c_1\,u(t) -c_2\,u(t)^2$ is separable with solution

$$
u(t) = \frac{c_1 e^{c_1(t+c_0)}}{1+c_2 e^{c_1(t+c_0)}}
$$

now calling $a_0 = \tanh^{-1}(\frac{c_{1}-2\,c_{2}\,w_{0}}{c_{1}}), k = \frac{c_1}{2c_2},\ b = \frac{c_1 t}{2}$ we have according to MATLAB

$$
-k\left(\frac{e^{a_0-b}-e^{-a_0+b}}{e^{a_0-b}+e^{-a_0+b}}-1\right) = k\frac{2e^{-2a_0+2b}}{1+e^{-2a_0+2b}}
$$

etc.

Comment: Why was my approach with substitution leading to a different result then?

Comment: also your solution: $\dfrac{c_{1}\,{\mathrm{e}}^{c_{1}\,\left(t+u_{0}\right)}}{c_{2}\,{\mathrm{e}}^{c_{1}\,\left(t+u_{0}\right)}+1}$ is a little displace compared to the plot of MATLAB's solution